# How to make a loop

Tags: python, loops

I am making this game Pokemon in python, but the very simple version. So far this is my code. What I am trying to do is that after Torchik has fainted, I would like it so that it loops back to the first line, if he's a boy or a girl and has to go through everything again. How would I go about doing this?

```
print("Now,", name, "are you a boy or a girl?")
gender=input()
print("Enough with the introduction, let us go to the world of Pokemon!")
enter=input("Press enter to continue")
print("You will now pick your starting Pokemon", name,"!")
if gender== 'boy' or gender== 'Boy':
    print("You have three choices for your starting Pokemon.")
    starterP=input("Would you rather Torchik, Mudkip, or Bulbasaur? Choose wisely.")
    if starterP=='Torchik' or starterP=='torchik':
        print("You have picked Torchik!")
        print("Now, what region would you like to go to first? Kanto, Hoenn, Magiko, Yanto, or Kati?")
        region1=input()
        if region1=='Kanto' or region1=='kanto':
            print("Kanto it is!")
            print("You are currently facing the Pokemon Master for the Kanto region!")
            attack=input("Would you like to use cut and hurt his Pokemon?")
            if attack=='yes' or attack=='Yes':
                print("Torchik attacked the foe Pokemon! The foe has fainted!")
            if attack=='no' or attack=='No':
                print("The foe has attacked you! Fellow Torchik has fainted!")
                print("Game over!")
```

Comment: Quick tip `gender.lower()=='boy'`

Comment: You make a loop with the `for` or `while` statement. Whatever tutorial you're learning Python from should cover both.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how a [loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) works:

```
while <condition>:
    do_something()
```

or

```
for running_variable in <iterator>:
    do_something(running_variable)
```

This can be used like:

```
running_total = 0
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
    running_total = running_total + i
    # this is running_total += i
# this is all just sum(range(1,11)) but....
```

or

```
while True: # True is, unsurprisingly, always True
    print("I'm an infinite loop!")
```

Infinite loops can be good for things like this, because you can use a couple of keywords to manipulate them: [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) and [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement). I would recommend that, but I'll leave implementation to you.